# How can I configure Geany to compile and run my Python programs?

Tags: python, geany

Under the Build menu, I can see 'Execute' option, but it is greyed out.

The only option available is 'Set Includes and Arguments'. When I click that both fields are already filled out. What do I have to write there?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your Compile, build configuration settings?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia Which operating system are you using?

Comment: What version of Geany?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't need to configure anything in Geany. I just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and the current module is executed.

Are you sure that your file is recognized as a Python source file? Which version of Geany are you using (I am using the SVN version, which is pretty stable; damn, it's rock solid stable ;-))? I have a slightly more developed configuration for Python compilation in my version, but the commands are the same and it works very well.

Comment: DUuuuuuuuuurrrrrrrrrr. I had to save the file first and then the options appeared. Go figure! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the following solution:

In the 'Build Options' dialogue, click on '_Execute' at the bottom of the dialogue and the _execute options become editable.

I put the full path name to my Python install in there (C:\Python27\python %F) or (C:\Python32\python %F) and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

For some unknown reason a new installed Geany at [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo) had **python "%f"** at *Build* → *Set Build Commands* → *Execute* default settings.

I solved a similar issue with **python3 "%f"** instead.

Comment: Thanks I just found your solution during a search to solve the same issue, I am on Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon and seeing as typing python in a terminal window won't work because python2 is dead and typing python3 is now needed to start python3, I am a bit surprised that this simple bug has not been fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Also *don’t* forget to set the “KeyBinding”, i.e., the keyboard *shortcut-key* (single or combination) you press to activate “Run, Execute, Compile, Save, Find, Print, etc...

To do so;

Menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Here you can choose/change any Key/s to map to any action you want.

Why? Because some other Linux program might have been overridden, or might have taken the default Geany assigned map keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path variables in the beginning. Or you need to set the variables in *Build* → set build commands.

This video can give you good clarity:

*[Install Geany for Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=428&v=5xGiSaRqroQ)*

Your compile path is looking fine. But in the execution path, give the full path of your python.exe. In my case it is...

**C:\python27\python "%f"**

Comment: Your compile path is lookin fine. But in the execution path give the full path of your python.exe. In my case it is..            **c:\python27\python "%f"**

Answer (score -1):

1. Find the Python console path.
2. Now set the environment variable

Comment: step ->1:check if python is installed by typing python in cmd . step->2 if installed but not showing the  it than find the path from right-click->properties    step3: set the environment variable and its done

Comment: What is the name of the environment variable?