# Geany-Python path execution failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, geany

I've just started learning python and am using the book: "Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes.

The book instructed me to create a folder called python_work, and save a file named "hello_world.py" in the "python_work" folder through the geany text editor. 
I checked the build and execute command paths and they seem to be the exact same as the path as my python command but when ever I hit execute the command terminal opens and exits immediately. 
Executing python in the cmd prompt isn't an issue, but for whatever reason it won't work through geany.

I've seen everywhere that python should be found in C:\Python35\python but mine is found C:\Users\Rob Hardy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe and that's what opens the Python program for me. 
Is there anything that I can do to fix this?

Comment: So your execute command is `"C:\Users\Rob Hardy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "%f"`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2094105/1025391

Comment: @Rawing yes my execute command is that

Comment: @moooeeeep that thread is the fix to my issue?