# Python and Geany portable on system with no admin rights

Tags: python, geany, portable-applications

I'm trying to learn Python on a system running Windows 7 with no admin rights.

Have downloaded Python Portable 3.2.5.1 and Geany Portable 1.31, ran the executable, all fine and dandy but got stuck on trying to compile the program I am trying to write (nothing fancy, just "hello world").

The issue I'm encountering is whenever I hit compile, i get an error in terminal window saying "'python' is not recognized [...] program exited with code: 9009".

Have tried to modify the build commands to the folder where my apps are located but to no avail.

My apps are located in C:\Users\My username\Downloads\Learning\python and C:\Users\My username\Downloads\Learning\GeanyPortable

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You most likely need to give Geany the path to where your portable Python is installed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094105/how-can-i-configure-geany-to-compile-and-run-my-python-programs

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for your reply. Let me dumb it down for others trying to learn Pyrhon on a work PC: 1. The path to your Python portable app should contain no spaces. 2. The Compile and Execute paths should also containg the path for the executable. Example: C:\Python_Portable\python-portable.exe